# Disabling/Enabling of form text boxes on click of checkbox and passing name of the text box as a parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a sample code where in I am disabling or enabling the textbox on click of checkbox.

```js
function enable_text(status) {
  status = !status;
  document.f1.other_text.disabled = status;
}
```

```html
<body onload=enable_text(false);>

  <form name=f1 method=post>
    <input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)">Others
    <input type=text name=other_text>
  </form>

</body>
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to repeat the javascript code for everytime I add a new checkbox and textbox in the form as the name of the checkbox has been hardcoded. How shall I make it dynamic so that once I have added a new textbox  with a checkbox it should take it dynamicaaly and enable it on clicking of checkbox

Comment: You tagged it with jquery so you're gonna accept a jquery solution or you want this to remain as plain js?

Comment: Actually Javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do with javascript code

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("chkbox");

var myFunction = function() {
if(this.checked == true){
this.closest(".parentDiv").getElementsByClassName("txtbox")[0].disabled = false;
   
}else{
  this.closest(".parentDiv").getElementsByClassName("txtbox")[0].disabled = true;
}
 
};
for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
  <form name=f1 method=post>
       <div class="parentDiv">
        <input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' name=others>Others
              <input type=text name=other_text class='txtbox' disabled='disabled'>
       </div>

          <div class="parentDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' name=others>Others
                  <input type=text name=other_text class='txtbox' disabled='disabled'>
          </div>
      </form>
```

This is how you can do with JQuery code

```js
$('.chkbox').on('click',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $(this).closest(".parentDiv").find('.txtbox').prop("disabled",false)
   }
   else{
   $(this).closest(".parentDiv").find('.txtbox').prop("disabled",true)
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name=f1 method=post>
       <div class="parentDiv">
        <input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' name=others>Others
              <input type=text name=other_text class='txtbox' disabled='disabled'>
       </div>

          <div class="parentDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' name=others>Others
                  <input type=text name=other_text class='txtbox' disabled='disabled'>
          </div>
          
          <div class="parentDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" class='chkbox' name=others>Others
                  <input type=text name=other_text class='txtbox' disabled='disabled'>
          </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The name of all textboxes are different. Then how will you do it

Comment: i am doing it with the class name so you can give different name for the textbox but with one common class name

Comment: OfCourse, You can check it, I have added code for Javascript as well

Answer (score 0):

This can accept as many checkbox/input as you want, as long as the `data-name` attribute of the checkbox is the same as the `name` attribute of the input element.

I used `querySelectorAll('input[class="checker"]')`, but this can be also replaced with `getElementsByClassName('checker')` *(since I'm selecting through class)*

I'm sure this can still be optimized, but I did this to show the connection between the checkbox and the input

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="checker"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].onclick = enable_text;
}

function enable_text() {
  var status = !this.checked;
  var name = this.getAttribute('data-name');
  var input = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]');
  input.disabled = status;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="checker" type="checkbox" name="others" data-name="other_text">Others
<input type="text" name="other_text" disabled>
<br/>
<input class="checker" type="checkbox" name="name" data-name="name_text">Name
<input type="text" name="name_text" disabled>
<br/>
<input class="checker" type="checkbox" name="address" data-name="address_text">Address
<input type="text" name="address_text" disabled>
<br/>
<input class="checker" type="checkbox" name="email" data-name="email_text">Email
<input type="text" name="email_text" disabled>
```

Comment: Please can you help me in javascript

Comment: @AbhayVarma Check again

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$(".txt").prop("disabled",true);
$(".section input:checkbox").change(function () {
 $(this).closest(".section").find('.txt').prop("disabled", !this.checked);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body >

  <form name=f1 method=post>
  <div class="section">
   <input type="checkbox" name=others  class="checkbox">Others1
    <input type=text name=other_text class="txt" >
  </div>
    <div class="section">
   <input type="checkbox" name=others  class="checkbox">Others2
    <input type=text name=other_text class="txt" >
  </div>
   <div class="section">
   <input type="checkbox" name=others  class="checkbox">Others3
    <input type=text name=other_text class="txt" >
  </div>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: You can use `.prop("disabled", !this.checked)` instead of `if/else` condition

Comment: The name of all textboxes are different. Then how will you do it

Comment: i have used the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting the checkbox change event and getting the next input box to the check box as shown in the code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).next('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false);
    
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).next('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <form name=f1 method=post>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' name=others>Others
    <input type='text' name=other_text>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='checked' name=others>Others
    <input type='text' name=other_text>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: The name of all textboxes are different. Then how will you do it

Comment: It doesn't effect. Its not working with name its working with its type